# ajax does not allow html class click functions to run

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I make a selection on test1.php it passes the value onchange="showbookings(this.value) to test2.php then returns filled in html code from a mysql call.  All of this works perfectly.

The problem I am having is the class functions contactus and status_button no longer work at all in email.js.  When I click on contactus...nothing happens.  When I click on status_button the page refreshes back to the unselected box. I am looking for suggestion on how to get the class functions to work after the selection is made and html rendered.

I have the functions working in another example without the selection rendering the html so I know that they work.  I just don't understand why they no longer work with the selection.

```
<a id='email1' href='#' class='contactus'><img src='emailbutton.jpg' title='Email' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></a>

<div id='messageA1'><a id='1' href='' class='status_button' title='C1'><div id='messageB1'><img src='closebutton.jpg' title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a></div>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

echo '<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="booking.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="email.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href=""><img src="/images/logo.png" height="123" width="298"></a>
    <br/>
    <form style="width: 1100px">
        <select name="bookings" onchange="showbookings(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Bookings To See:</option>
            <option value="1">All Booking</option>
            <option value="2">Open Bookings</option>
            <option value="3">Closed Bookings</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="txtBookings"></div>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

test2.php is run and returns the following html filled in from mysql back to the

```
  <div id="txtBookings"></div>
```

on test1.php

```
<form id='form1' style='width: 1100px'>
    <table>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <th>Adults</th>
        <th>Kids</th>
        <th>Pets</th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='id1' size='3' readonly='readonly' value='1'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='fname1' size='8' value='Bob'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='lname1' size='13' value='Smith'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='email1' size='25' value='bobsmith@yahoo.com'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='phone1' size='10' value='(555)-555-5555'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='addy1' size='22' value='123 Main St'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='city1' size='10' value='Anywhere'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='state1' size='1' value='CA'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='zip1' size='2' value='99999'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='adults1' size='2' value='2'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='kids1' size='1' value='0'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='pet1' size='1' value='0'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Check In</th>
        <th>Check Out</th>
        <th>Booked</th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='level1' size='2' value='Upper'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='chkin1' size='7' value='11/21/2013'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='chkout1' size='7' value='11/24/2013'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='booked1' size='7' value='10/02/2013'>
            </td>
            <td><a id='edit1' href='' class='edit_button' title=''><img src='editbutton.jpg' title='Submit Edit' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></a>
            </td>
            <td><a id='email1' href='#' class='contactus'><img src='emailbutton.jpg' title='Email' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id='messageA1'><a id='1' href='' class='status_button' title='C1'><div id='messageB1'><img src='closebutton.jpg' title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

email.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".contactus").click (function () {
//    alert("email");
        var element = $(this);
        var J = element.attr("id");
        var email = document.getElementById(J).value;
        $("#result").html("<h3>Loading</h3>").css("display", "block");
        findCenter($("#result"));
        $.get("email.php?email=" + email, function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            findCenter($("#result"));
            FocusOnInput();
            $("#snd").click(function () {
                var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
                var addy = document.getElementById("addy").value;
                var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;
                $("#result").append("<br /><br /><div><i>Sending...</i></div>");
                $.post("email.php", {
                    mode: "snd",
                    subject: subject,
                    addy: addy,
                    comments: comments
                }, function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    findCenter($("#result"));
                });
            });
            $("#cnx").click(function () {
                $.post("email.php", {
                    mode: "cnx"
                }, function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    findCenter($("#result"));
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".status_button").click (function () {
//    alert("status");
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var id = $("#id" + I).val();
        var sname = $(this).attr("title");
        $.post("openclose.php", {
            id: id,
            sname: sname
        },

        function (data) {
            var response = (data).split(";", 3);
            $("#messageA" + I).innerhtml = (response[0]);
            $("#messageA" + I).hide();
            $("#messageA" + I).fadeIn(1500);
            $("#messageB" + I).html(response[1]);
            $("#messageB" + I).hide();
            $("#messageB" + I).fadeIn(1500);
            document.getElementById(I).value = (response[2]);
            document.getElementById(I).title = (response[2] + I);
        });
        return false;
    });
});


function showbookings(str) {
    if (str === "") {
        document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "test2.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reattach the click event listener after you load your dynamic content. The bindings only occur for elements that are already on the page when the listener is attached. The listener is NOT attached to elements added to the DOM after the `on()` call is made.

After you make your ajax call, you will need to do `$(".status_button").on('click',function(){....});` to bind the click event to any new `.status_button` elements.

From the jQuery docs for `on()`

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

Comment: adear11 - thanks for the response. How and where do I reattach the click event listeners? You wrote "After your ajax call...bind the click event to any new .status_button elements." There are no .status_button elements before the ajax call so they are all new. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks, Kurt

Comment: You should do it in your `onreadystatechange` function, after you assign the innerHTML

Comment: do you have a script example I could see?  Thanks,  Kurt

Comment: If you use the delegate form of `on()`, the selector doesn't have to exist on the page at that time. From docs: "When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector."

Answer (score 1):

Bind your click event handlers like this, using a delegated event handler so that they will work for dynamically generated HTML elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.status_button', function () {
   // your code here
};
```

The way you have it, (binding with just `$(".status_button").click(...)`), the elements do not exist yet when the click event handler is bound, which is why it doesn't work.  The `on()` method in the delegate form will work even for elements not yet created at the time that the handler is bound.

For better performance, you could also attach it to the closest ancestor of `.status_button` that will already exist at the time of binding the event (replace `'body'` with the selector for that ancestor).

From Documentation (go down to delegated event handlers):

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: mayabelle - I appreciate your response back.  I tried .on and .live and got no different results. Kurt

Comment: Not really, but you have what you need already. All you need to do is move the `$('.status_button').click()` method call that is currently in your `$(document).ready()` function to right after `document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: @Kurt Sorry, I used the wrong form of on() previously; you have to use the delegate form for it to work on dynamically created elements. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice and added the functions together. The following is what I did. All functions work exactly as they should.

```
function showbookings(str) {
    if (str === "") {
        document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

       $(".contactus").on('click', function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var J = element.attr("id");
        var email = document.getElementById(J).value;
        $("#result").html("<h3>Loading</h3>").css("display", "block");
        findCenter($("#result"));
        $.get("email.php?email=" + email, function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            findCenter($("#result"));
            FocusOnInput();
            $("#snd").click(function () {
                var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
                var addy = document.getElementById("addy").value;
                var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;
                $("#result").append("<br /><br /><div><i>Sending...</i></div>");
                $.post("email.php", {
                    mode: "snd",
                    subject: subject,
                    addy: addy,
                    comments: comments
                }, function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    findCenter($("#result"));
                });
            });
            $("#cnx").click(function () {
                $.post("email.php", {
                    mode: "cnx"
                }, function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    findCenter($("#result"));
                });
            });
        });
    });
    $(".status_button").on('click', function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var id = $("#id" + I).val();
        var sname = $(this).attr("title");
        $.post("openclose.php", {
            id: id,
            sname: sname
        },
        function (data) {
            var response = (data).split(";", 3);
            $("#messageA" + I).innerhtml = (response[0]);
            $("#messageA" + I).hide();
            $("#messageA" + I).fadeIn(1500);
            $("#messageB" + I).html(response[1]);
            $("#messageB" + I).hide();
            $("#messageB" + I).fadeIn(1500);
            document.getElementById(I).value = (response[2]);
            document.getElementById(I).title = (response[2] + I);
        });
        return false;
    });
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "test2.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```